# Production database not created by rake db:create command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im a Rails beginner and am using Rails 3 on Ubuntu 10.10. My database.yml is as follows.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: project_dev
  username: root
  password: rootpassword
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: project_test
  username: root
  password: rootpassword
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: project_production
  username: root
  password: rootpassword
  host: localhost
```

Then i switched to the project folder and ran the command:

```
rake db:create
```

But,only the project_dev and project_test databases were created. The project_production database did not exist in mysql. What could the problem here ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 64):

That is the way it is intended to be. To create the production database do:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

Also, have a look at `rake db:setup` which will run anything you put in `db/seeds.rb`.

Answer (score 9):

This is by design as @iain suggests. To create all databases, run `rake db:create:all`.

Comment: This will create development and test databases too.